# Will a Shimano Deore 11 speed chain work on a SRAM NX 11 speed drivetrain?

Tags: shimano, chain, compatibility, drivetrain, sram

I went to a bike shop today and got a complete service and new chain. When I looked at the tax invoice, it said it was a Shimano Deore 11 speed chain, however I have SRAM NX 11 speed drive train. I searched it up and it says it will work, however I was wondering if there are any issues that will occur in the long run, like the chain wearing out the teeth of the cosset faster then normal. Thanks

Update: I’ve read all the comments and I have kept riding it with no issues so I believe it will be fine, I also asked some friends and they have shimano on sram and vise versa and haven’t had any issues.

Comment: I don't think so. A 11-speed chain is an 11-speed chain and shouldn't wear out teeth faster because roller and side plate dimensions match, it is more likely that a worn cassette kills the chain faster but that applies to any chain/cassette combination. I'm not entirely sure if Shimano has some optimizations like Linkglide/Hyperglide at this tier that SRAM would need to license and thus hasn't implemented - could be that you have slightly better shift quality on an original chain but it might not be perceivable at all.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest possible answer is yes, there aren't issues.

A slightly longer answer is: most road and MTB chains follow the same general standard. Shimano 11s road and MTB drivetrains may shift slightly more nicely with their own chains than with other chains. I think SRAM is not like this. A Shimano chain will gain no advantage on a SRAM drivetrain, the chain and the cassette ramps have to be designed to work with each other.

SRAM 12 speed systems start to diverge from that standard above. You have to use their flat top chains with AXS road or Transmission MTB systems. Shimano and Campagnolo 12s chains can still be interchanged.

Comment: The situation in 12-speed is a bit different: On 12-speed, Shimano has introduced a new ramp system/tooth profile — Hyperglide+ (and is only using it in their 12s chains), that is in theory compatible with non-hyperglide+ components, but may lead to accelerated wear. In 12-speed, SRAM has two designs: the "evolution of 11-speed, and flattop, not compatible).

Comment: I haven't heard any indications that mixing Shimano HG+ components with non-HG+ will result in accelerated *wear*. You'll lose the enhanced shifting for sure.

Comment: https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/chain-compatibility-by-chainring-tooth-profile (short version: Hyperglide+ inner plates are chamfered, so it creates contact points that do not exist in non-HG+ chains).